# Create an array of objects by splitting a string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have string that input from user like this `var str="aa bb cc"`

Can I need like this

```
mylists = [ 
           { "0": "11", "1": "aa" }, 
           { "0": "aa", "1": "bb" }, 
           { "0": "bb", "1": "cc" }, 
           { "0": "cc", "1": "11" }, .... 
          ]`
```

Note: first and last value must be `11`

this is the code I have tried

```
var str =$("#gettxt").val(); //my value get from user input`

console.log(str );
var parts = str.split(" ");
var numpro =countString(str); //i have other function count word in string that user input
tbl+="";
var listt = [];
for (i = 0; i < numpro; i++) {
    listt.push({
        0:"11",
        1:parts[i]
    })
}
console.log(listt)
```

Comment: What is the output of the code, which you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

After splitting your string, you can add a leading and trailing `11` to the array, and then make up each object from the current and next element in the array:

```js
// user input string
var str="aa bb cc"

// split and add leading and trailing `11`
var parts = ['11'].concat(str.split(" ")).concat('11');
var numpro = parts.length;
var listt = [];
for (i = 0; i < numpro-1; i++) {
    listt.push({
        0:parts[i],
        1:parts[i+1]
    })
}
console.log(listt)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the array unshift() 11 always to be at the beginning of the array and then use `map`

```js
var str="aa bb cc"
arr=str.split(" ")
arr.unshift("11")
res=arr.map((n,i)=>({"0":n,"1":arr[i+1]||"11"}))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: You' re Welcome, conceder upvoting and accepting my answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array by splitting the string and adding `"11"` at the beginning and the end. Then create an array using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and spread a chunk of the array inside the `{}` to create an object with numeric indices.

```js
const str = "aa bb cc",
      parts = ["11", ...str.split(" "), "11"],
      length = parts.length - 1,
      output = Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => ({ ...parts.slice(i, i+2) }))

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `map` and `split` in one line

```js
const getArray = (str, fill = "11") =>
  [...str.split(" "), fill].map((x, i, arr) => ({
    0: arr[i - 1] ?? fill,
    1: x,
  }));

var str = "aa bb cc";
console.log(getArray(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#map` with an additional `push` call at the end.

```
let parts = str.split(' ');
let res = parts.map((x,idx)=>({0: idx === 0 ? "11" : parts[idx - 1], 1: x}));
res.push({0: parts[parts.length - 1], 1: "11"});
```

The additional push at the end can be avoided by appending `" 11"` to the string before splitting.

```
let parts = (str + " 11").split(' ');
let res = parts.map((x,idx)=>({0: idx === 0 ? "11" : parts[idx - 1], 1: x}));
```